# PyQT Table Model Data Binding

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I have one QML that using TableView for display content and i need dynamically inject data from my python code to qt QML table .

QML below :

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2


ApplicationWindow {
//property var tableModel
      title: qsTr("Hello World")
      width: 640
      height: 480
      TableView {
           model: tableModel
           anchors.fill: parent
           Component.onCompleted: console.log(tableModel)
           TableViewColumn {
                width:200
                role: "hello_would"
                title: "Hello Would"
      }
      TableViewColumn {
          width:200
          role: "foobar"
          title: "Foobar"
      }
      TableViewColumn {
          width:200
          role: "zebra"
          title: "Zebra"
      }
      TableViewColumn {
          width:200
          role: "ummmm"
          title: "Ummmm"
      }

  }
}
```

So i attempt implement QtAbstractTableModel , here is my implementation .

```
import sys
import collections

from PyQt5 import Qt


class DummyList(Qt.QAbstractTableModel):
    __DEFAULT__ = Qt.QVariant()
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(DummyList,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.__roles = {}
        self.__data = []
        self.append_data(
            [
                ("hello_would", "HELOOWOULD",),
                ("foobar" , "ECHO",),
                ("zebra"  , "FOO",),
                ("ummmm"  , "BAR",)
            ],True
        )


    def append_data(self,value,header_update=False):

        last_index = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(Qt.QModelIndex(),last_index,last_index)
        value = collections.OrderedDict(value)
        self.__data.append(value)
        self.endInsertRows()
        if header_update:
            for key in value.keys():
                if key not in self.__roles.values():
                    self.__roles[ Qt.Qt.UserRole + len(self.__roles) ] = key


    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role):

        if role == Qt.Qt.DisplayRole:
            column = self.__roles.get(Qt.Qt.UserRole + section,Qt.QVariant())
        else:
            column = self.__roles.get(role,Qt.QVariant())
        return column


    def columnCount(self,parent=Qt.QModelIndex()):

        return len(self.__data[0])


    def rowCount(self,parent=Qt.QModelIndex()):

        return len(self.__data)


    def roleNames(self):
        """
        Model only invoked while binding to QML view .
        """
        default_roles = super(DummyList,self).roleNames()
        default_roles.update({ key:Qt.QByteArray(value.encode()) for key,value in self.__roles.items()})
        return default_roles


    def data(self,index,role):

        row = index.row()
        if index.isValid():
            if role >= Qt.Qt.UserRole:
                """
                Only fire on binding to QML
                """
                column = self.__roles[role]
            elif role == Qt.Qt.DisplayRole:
                column = self.__roles[Qt.Qt.UserRole + index.column()]
            else:
                return DummyList.__DEFAULT__
            col_data = self.__data[row][column]
            return Qt.QVariant(col_data)
        else:
            return DummyList.__DEFAULT__


class MyWindow(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Qt.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tablemodel = DummyList(self)
        tableview = Qt.QTableView()
        tableview.setModel(tablemodel)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)


def main(*args,**kwargs):
    # We instantiate a QApplication passing the arguments of the script to it:
    main_app = Qt.QApplication(list(args))

    """
    Load tableview in QML , it will Segmentation fault: 11
    or display empty table
    """

    qml_app_engine = Qt.QQmlApplicationEngine(
        main_app
    )
    qml_app_engine.rootContext().setContextProperty(
        "tableModel",
         DummyList()
    )#If set property here , raise segementation most time
    qml_app_engine.load(Qt.QUrl(sys.path[0]+"/hello_table.qml"))
    qml_app_engine.rootContext().setContextProperty(
        "tableModel",
        DummyList()
    )#Nothing to show , but data method has been invoked
    new_root = qml_app_engine.rootObjects()[0]

    new_root.show()


    """
    Load with custom create widget , everything is fine , 
    """
    #w = MyWindow()
    #w.show()

    # Now we can start it.
    return_code = main_app.exec_()
    return return_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(*sys.argv))
```

But it don't work , just show the empty table with header .

Anyone know my wrong ?

Updated 2015/04/06 :

I also test other cases .

Case one : invoke `setContextProperty` before `load` QML.

Case two : invoke `setContextProperty` after `load` QML.

Case three : Don't use `QMlApplicationEngine` , directly use `MyWindow` to show data .

In case one , that may cause two result .

Result 1 : Report segmentation fault: 11 , system exit .

Result 2 : Display empty table with header . `QtAbstractTableModel` not invoked . `Component.onCompleted: console.log(tableModel)` print null

In case two , everything in fine , all function in `QtAbstractTableModel` has been called . `Component.onCompleted: console.log(tableModel)` don't invoked . 
But table still empty .

My console output in case two listed below , seen data method has been invoked and work correctly.

```
 2015-04-05 16:58:49,244 DEBUG decorator:24 data args : (<app.models.dummy.DummyList object at 0x1094680d8>, <PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x109470438>, 7) , kwargs : {}
 2015-04-05 16:58:49,244 DEBUG decorator:26 data result : Foobar - P1
 2015-04-05 16:58:49,244 DEBUG decorator:24 data args : (<app.models.dummy.DummyList object at 0x1094680d8>, <PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x109470438>, 8) , kwargs : {}
 2015-04-05 16:58:49,244 DEBUG decorator:26 data result : Zebra - P1
 2015-04-05 16:58:49,245 DEBUG decorator:24 data args : (<app.models.dummy.DummyList object at 0x1094680d8>, <PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x109470438>, 9) , kwargs : {}
 2015-04-05 16:58:49,245 DEBUG decorator:26 data result : Ummmm - P1
```

In case three : All work , display data correctly . But i must using QML instead of manually create widget .

Comment: Forgot add my development environments .
I development under MacOS , python3.4 and Qt5

Answer (score 0):

i found how to make my code work !

I just change

```
qml_app_engine = Qt.QQmlApplicationEngine(
    main_app
)
qml_app_engine.rootContext().setContextProperty(
    "tableModel",
     DummyList()
) # If set property here , raise segementation most time
```

to

```
mod = DummyList()
qml_app_engine = Qt.QQmlApplicationEngine(
    main_app
)
qml_app_engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("tableModel",mod) # If set property here , raise segementation most time
qml_app_engine.load(Qt.QUrl(sys.path[0]+"/hello_table.qml"))
```

Just change the time to instantialize model instance , my code work .

But any qt expert can explain why this change work ?